# SQL Server syntax for a delete trigger with date parameter

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a trigger for DELETE action, in Microsoft SQL Server, so that a 
line in my table can't be deleted if column Expiry Date > sysdate.

Table example:

```
| Warranty | Expiry Date      |
+----------+------------------+
| product  | 19 - DEC - 2020  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table dbo.t (Warranty varchar(100), Expiry_Date date);
insert into dbo.t values 
('product', '20201219'),
('product 2015', '20151219');
 go

 create trigger tr_selective_delete on dbo.t instead of delete
 as
    set nocount on;
    delete t
    from dbo.t t
         join deleted d
            on t.Warranty = d.Warranty
    where t.Expiry_Date <= getdate();

delete dbo.t;

select *
from dbo.t;
----
--product   2020-12-19
```

Note that the join field(`Warranty` in your case) should be `unique`.